# Email sending error by mailgun API in php

Tags: mailgun

I am trying to send mail with mailgum API.
As it shared server, I can't install composer( to load mailgun SDK). Instead, I am using curl.
here is my code:

```
function send_simple_message() {  
$api_key = "key-9dc0bf ... 2e4c1007d0ebd7c8";
$domain=     "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox.mailgun.org";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
            array('from' => 'Ruhul Amin <testemail@gmail.com>',
                  'to' => 'Michael Scott <test2@gmail.com>',
                  'subject' => 'The Printer Caught Fire',
                  'text' => 'We have a problem.'));
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
}

var_dump ( send_simple_message() );

?>
```

Output is: 
     bool(false)

But not email is sent.
Could you please tell me what is my problem.
Thanks.

Ruhul

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem. I am posting here, hope it will help some one.
Actually, CURLOPT_USERPWD - user name and password to use in authentication
So, In my case, the user name is : api and user password is the API-key
I need to merge the same while defining the $api-key

```
function send_simple_message() {  
$api_key = "api:key-9dc0bf ... 2e4c1007d0ebd7c8";
$domain=     "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox.mailgun.org";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        array('from' => 'Ruhul Amin <testemail@gmail.com>',
              'to' => 'Michael Scott <test2@gmail.com>',
              'subject' => 'The Printer Caught Fire',
              'text' => 'We have a problem.'));
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
}

var_dump ( send_simple_message() );
```

Answer (score 0):

If [curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) returns `false`, it means there was an error. You can fetch the error message with [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) function. See the output of the `curl_error` function and you will be closer to have it working. Example code:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false)
{
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    // do something with the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $mailgun_api_url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "api:{$mailgun_api_key}",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        "from" => "emailfrom@app.com",
        "to" => "emailto@app.com",
        "subject" => "subject of mail",
        "text" => "description/content of the mail."
    ]
]);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

make sure that $mailgun_api_url and $mailgun_api_key should be correct and check the $res it should be json like below

```
{
    "id": "<messageid@domain.com>",
    "message": "Queued. Thank you."
}
```

the message is send if the receiving email id is correct.